# Linq GroupBy include empty keys

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I've got some elements of a hierarchy. These Elements I want to group.

```
cuttingTools = machines.SelectMany(x0 => x0.Operations)
                       .SelectMany(x1 => x1.Tools)
                       .SelectMany(x2 => x2.CuttingTools)
                       .GroupBy(x => x.Tool.Operation.Machine) as IQueryable<IGrouping<T, CuttingTool>>;
```

But I've got one big problem. If a machine does not have any child operations, tools or cuttingtools the result does not contain the empty groups. For example:

```
Machine Tool
M1  T1
M1  T2
M1  T3
M2  T1
M2  T2
M3  Null

M1 [T1, T2, T3]
M2 [T1, T2]
M3 [None]
```

But currently, the M3 won't appear in the result. How can I include M3 even if it has no elements.

Comment: I though `group by` will at least list all the group keys, the elements of some group may **empty** but the **key** should be listed in the groups.

Comment: I'm not sure this is doable in Lambda. I have a LINQ expression that works, that is if I'm understanding your data structure correctly, if you'd like to see it?

Comment: Thanks. The correct solution is mentioned in the answer of Alexander @Ally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to create some empty placeholder value for your empty elements. DefaultIfEmpty can do this. Note that in sample below I group directly by parent machine, without accessing tool internal properties (x.Tool.Operation.Machine in your case). If this is not possible in your scenario - you would need to somehow dynamically create and initialize default values with references to parent.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Machine
{
  public string MachineName;
  public Operation[] Operations;
}

class Operation
{
  public string OperationName;
  public Tool[] Tools;
}

class Tool
{
  public string ToolName;
  public Tool(string name) { ToolName = name; }
}

class App
{
  static void Main()
  {
    var machines = new[] 
    {
      new Machine {
        MachineName = "A", Operations = new[] { new Operation { OperationName = "O1", Tools = new[] { new Tool("T1") } } }
      },
      new Machine {
        MachineName = "B", Operations = new[] { new Operation { OperationName = "O3", Tools = new Tool[0] } }
      },
      new Machine {
        MachineName = "C", Operations = new Operation[0]
      }
    };

    var defaultOp = new Operation() { Tools = new Tool[0] };
    var defaultTool = new Tool("");

    var res = 
    from m in machines
    from o in m.Operations.DefaultIfEmpty(defaultOp)
    from t in o.Tools.DefaultIfEmpty(defaultTool)
    group t by m.MachineName;

    foreach(var g in res)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(g.Key + "=" + string.Join(";", g.Select(x => x.ToolName)));
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
A=T1
B=
C=
```

Comment: Thanks. The left join by adding the DefaultIfEmpty solved my problem.